# Does inline css affect the value from a form?

Tags: php, css, forms, input

I have input in html like this.

```
<input name="hoteltaxi" type="text" style="text-transform: uppercase;">
```

These inputs send the information throughout a post method. The PHP file that receive the information, got to save it in a mysql database. 
To this point, is ok. Everything is working, but i have a little question about the form style.

If css can transform the value presentation... can also transform the value that i send to php? ¿Or is just presentation? Because, i really need to see this in uppercase, but i need to store with PHP in the original string format (can also be numbers, lowercases, and uppercases, doesn't matter) because from the original string, previously stored, will use it to make a MD5 hash.

The code is my frenemy.

Comment: The easiest way to test this would be to submit the form and `var_dump` the output. Did you try that yet? My presumption would be it doesn't affect the actual contents.

Comment: css will not change actual value that posted to php. you can change it by using js or at php side.

Comment: Thanks for your answers :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **No**

You can see it clearly in this screenshot

[image]

If you really want the data to be transformed to uppercase do it on server side like this

```
$hoteltaxi = strtoupper($_POST['hoteltaxi']);
```

*more about [strtoupper](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php)*

Or if you want it to be done on client-side a little bit of javascript can help you

```
$('input[name="hoteltaxi"]').change(function(){ 
    var self = $(this);
    self.val(self.val().toUpperCase())
})
```